# Is there anyway to seperately supply data into if_else clause

Tags: t-sql

I try to run If-Else in sql and the problem is when an output state 2 row of count only one row is used in the code

```
.....

declare SameSongName cursor for
  select artist
  from playlist
  where SongName = @songname

set  @artist = (select artist from playlist where songname = @songname)

set  @count = (select [count] from totalusage where songname = @songname)

set @rank = (select [rank] from TotalUsage where songname = @songname)

/* problem is one songname may has 2 artist and that cause it has 2 rank and only 1 row is implemented but i need 2] */

  if @rank < 6
   begin

   open SameSongName
   fetch next from  SameSongName 
   into @artist

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin


     print ' Top 5 '
     print '***************'
     print rtrim(@songname)+' by '+ rtrim(@artist) + ' is in rank ' +convert (char (5), @rank) 
      print '***************'
      print 'This song was listened for ' + convert(char(20),@count) 
fetch next from  SameSongName 
   into @artist
      close SameSongName
    deallocate SameSongName

   end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT7Ws.png)

problem occurs when same songname may show different rank

Comment: Please give table and data examples along with current and desired output so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I just add image url(not able to inert hte whole pic because of my rank. hope it help, thank you in advance)

Comment: OK Given these n10 records what is your desires ourput? You can edit your post and put them in a table there.

Comment: Hi Edney Holder, We cannot query image. instead of stories and images, please provide (1) Queries to CREATE your tables including indexes. (2) Queries to INSERT sample data. (3) The desired result given the sample, as text or image of excel for example. (4) A short description of the business rules, and how you got 1-2 of the results. (5) Which version of SQL Server you are using (this will help to fit the query to your version). **In short, you should provide the tools which we can use in order to reproduce the issue** ;-)